# How to read muliple csv files and merge them?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

These are my csv files which exist in a specific directory:

```
output0
output1
output3
output4

out0
out1
out2
out3
```

I should merge output0 with out0 , output1 with out1 ect ..

I merged just output0 with out0 but I didn't find a way to do this with the rest of the file

PS: this is an example only, I have 100's of csv files in my directory

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import time
a = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/AQ42770/Documents/merge/output0.csv")
b = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/AQ42770/Documents/merge/out0.csv")
merged = a.merge(b, on='Class')
merged.to_csv("output.csv", index=False)

time.sleep(60)
df = pd.read_csv("output.csv")
k=df.loc[~df.Class.duplicated(keep='last')]
k.to_csv("test1.csv", index=False, na_rep='NaN')
```

Comment: do it inside `for-loop` - and use value from `for` to create file name `output0`, `output1`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a for loop and string formatting to create 2 variables, `str_a` and `str_b`. Then read those variables into `pd.read_csv`

Something like:

```
for i in range(number_of _files):
    str_a = "path/to/file%d.csv" % i
    str_b = "path/to/otherfile%d.csv" % i

    a = pd.read_csv(str_a)
    b = pd.read_csv(str_b)
```

Comment: thanks but there are errors : `a = pd.read_csv(str_a)`   `Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'NoneType'>` any help!

Comment: I've tried this on some test files and it worked fine but I am using Linux so the paths are specified a little differently, from your error I suspect there is a problem with the path you are using, double check the path your specifying definitely exists, it is being typed correctly, and that pd.read_csv can accept all the characters in that string (I've seen colons in paths cause problems before)

Answer (score 1):

You can get a list of CSV files with `glob`, read all of them in a loop into a list of DataFrames, and concatenate the members of the resulting list:

```
import glob
df = pd.concat(pd.read_csv(f) for f in glob.glob("*.csv"))
```

Comment: Thanks I find this but the problem that I should not merge them together .I should merge output0 with out0 and output1 with out1 not all !